# How to get integer value from QSpinBox changed value?

Tags: c++, qt

Here, I am just trying to obtain the changed `int` value from `QSpinBox` by using `SIGNAL and SLOTS` because I need to use this `int` variable in my another function. I mean if the user changes `QSpinBox` values, it changes the value of `int` variable.

I know this `SIGNAL` will be `SIGNAL(valueChanged(int))`, but I got confused about what the `SLOT` will be in this case. I really got stack on this point.

**EDIT:**

What I have tried is following. `MainWindow.h` is

```
#include <QMainWindow>
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void setFrame(int frame);
```

MainWindow.cpp is following. To check how it is working I tried to display the `int` in a `QLabel`.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->spinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setFrame(int frame)));
}
void MainWindow::setFrame(int frame)
{
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(frame));

}
```

Can anyone fix this regarding how to get the changed `int` value from `QSpinBox`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ***about what the SLOT will be in this case.*** `SLOT(yourFunctionToCall(int))` Name yourFunctionToCall to whatever you want. Make sure it is listed in the slots section of your header for your class.

Comment: I have tried how you explained, but still not getting. I have edited my post, and added the codes. Can you tell me if I have done any mistake?

Comment: Change `SLOT(setFrame(int frame))` to `SLOT(setFrame(int))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation states (in [this document about QObject Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect)):

> Note that the signal and slots parameters must not contain any variable names

So your mistake is specifying the variable name in the slot `SLOT(setFrame(int frame))`. As you must only use the variable type, it would be instead `SLOT(setFrame(int))`.

Anyway, if that's the only objective of the connect, I would rather do:

```
connect(ui->spinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), ui->label, SLOT(setNum(int)));
```

That way, you don't even need the method `setFrame` in your MainWindow and labels already have a way to show numbers instead of strings.

Hope this helps!